# Anchor tag in href="{{store url=

Tags: magento, url, anchor, store

could some of you tell me how I can linke to an anchor tag while using this kind of linking:

```
href="{{store url="catalog/product/view" id="$row_item.product.id"}}"
```

Where do I have to put the "#anchor" part? Putting it behind the "view" part wont work as the id follows after it...

Many Thanks

Comment: you need to pass a parameter in the url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the link, like this:

```
href="{{store url="catalog/product/view" id="$row_item.product.id"}}#anchor"
```